# A required class was missing while executing com.microsoft.azure:azure-functions-maven-plugin:0.1.10:package

Tags: maven, azure

I am getting the following error:

```
Execution package-functions of goal com.microsoft.azure:azure-functions-maven-plugin:0.1.10:package failed: A required class was missing while executing com.microsoft.azure:azure-functions-maven-plugin:0.1.10:package: org/jdom2/filter/Filter
```

From the image the `org/jdom2/filter/Filter` [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvQPF.png)

I am trying to add `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.6</version>`
Not sure how to resolve the issue.
Getting the above error when i run mvn package with the following pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.xml_read_write</groupId>
    <artifactId>xml-read-write</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Azure Java Functions</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <functionAppName>xml-read-write-20180304140948539</functionAppName>
        <functionAppRegion>westus</functionAppRegion>
    </properties>

    <!--<dependencyManagement>-->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-functions-java-core</artifactId>
            <version>[1.0.0-beta-1,1.0.0)</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>

            <!--<systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/lib/jdom2-2.0.6.jar</systemPath>-->
            <!--<scope>system</scope>-->
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <!--</dependencyManagement>-->

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                    <artifactId>azure-functions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.1.10</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-functions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <resourceGroup>java-functions-group</resourceGroup>
                    <appName>${functionAppName}</appName>
                    <region>${functionAppRegion}</region>
                    <appSettings>
                        <property>
                            <name>FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION</name>
                            <value>beta</value>
                        </property>
                    </appSettings>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>package-functions</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>package</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/azure-functions/${functionAppName}
                            </outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>host.json</include>
                                        <include>local.settings.json</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Have you checked the log output for things like download issues ? permissions for accessing remote repositories like central or your own repository ?

Comment: Please review (and accept) my answer below - you need to move the maven-shade-plugin to the top of the plugins list.

Answer (score 0):

There is an order requirement for the maven-shade-plugin [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-java-worker) that isn't specified in the doc - it needs to be first, before the azure-functions-maven-plugin.

Comment: unfortunately i'm getting the same error even with the reordering :( Did it work for you on jdk 8 ?

Comment: Yes, jdk 8 and moving the shade plugin to the top works for me.